# BigDecimal: how to set up the scale once

Tags: javascript

I'm using [Daniel Trebbien's BigDecimal library](https://github.com/dtrebbien/BigDecimal.js), and I'm trying to set the scale to a fixed number of decimals.

I'm using a factory method to create all decimals in my app with the same scale:

```
function newBigDecimal(x){
    return (new BigDecimal(x)).setScale(2, BigDecimal.prototype.ROUND_HALF_UP);
}
```

So when I call BigDecimal.toString over a bigdecimal, or the negation, addition or substraction of them, the resulting string contains the expected number of decimals. Example:

```
var pi = newBigDecimal("3.1416");
console.log(pi.toString());
//returns "3.14"

var e = newBigDecimal("2.7182");
console.log(e.toString());
//returns "2.72"
```

But when I multiply, the resulting decimal has twice as many decimals as the originals:

```
var product = pi.multiply(e);
console.log(product.toString());
//returns "8.5408"
```

I'd have to call setScale again to get the result formatted with the desired number of decimals.

Is there a way to configure the scale once, so that the library always work with and returns decimals with the desired scale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a multiplication, new decimal numbers are generated. The library is preserving them by default instead of losing information, which is correct.

What I needed was actually formatting. So I've redefined BigDecimal.toString as follows:

```
    (function(){
        var oldToString = BigDecimal.prototype.toString;

        BigDecimal.prototype.toString = function(){
            return oldToString.apply(this.setScale(2, BigDecimal.prototype.ROUND_HALF_UP));
        };  
    })();
```

Comment: Couldn't you have done it without modifying the prototype and writing a specific formatting function like I said in my answer? I'm not a javascript expert but I've always heard that messing with prototypes is a bad idea.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester Yes, I could have done that, but then I'd have to search the code for every call to `BigInteger.toString` and call the formatting function from there. Time is money.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're approaching this the wrong way. The number of decimals shouldn't be a matter of how the data is stored in your app, it should be a matter of **formatting** the BigDecimal at the moment when you want to **represent** it as a string. I'd create a function that looks like this:

```
function formatBigDecimal(decimals) {
   //return string with provided amount of decimals
}
```

And use this every time you want to print.

I think setting the scale only needs to make sure that *enough* decimals are stored, i.e for calculation purposes I wouldn't truncate to 2 decimals at the moment of creation. Always round as late as possible for maximum accuracy.

I can't immediately find an API reference of that library but you'll figure it out I suppose.

Comment: I also think that the calculations should be made with as much info as available. The problem is that I need to display intermediate results, and the final result might differ from what the user expects based on those already rounded intermediate results. Also, for most cases (currencies) it makes no sense to work with more than 2 decimal places.

Comment: @MisterSmith if it makes no sense using more than 2 decimal places, why use BigDecimal at all? By the way, currencies and money should never use floats. They are represantable with integers that you just divide by 100 (dollars, euros, pounds etc) at the moment of display to the user.

Comment: That would be the best alternative, and I personally have done it like you said in previous projects, but for several reasons it is not an option here.